# Handling multiple Java exceptions in a library

Tags: java, exception

I have a simple minimal HTTP library supporting mutual TLS (on Android) and in this library I make calls involving several SSL-related APIs.  In the end, there are many exceptions. Thus one of my setup APIs throws several exceptions, for example this list:

```
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws CertificateException 
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException 
 * @throws KeyStoreException 
 * @throws UnrecoverableKeyException 
 * @throws KeyManagementException
```

That's ugly for the caller to have to write all those catch statements. If I were to catch the exceptions in the library and throw a single exception like

```
IllegalArgumentException
```

and put in the message the name of the original exception and its message, would the caller lose any information? Assume that one has to be backward compatible to Java 1.6 (for older Androids). Given that exceptions are often used to indicate errors it would seem that just creating the single exception would be much easier for the caller and nothing significant would be lost. But I do not see it being done so I assume I must be wrong and am missing something.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html

Comment: IllegalArgumentException is used to signal... an illegal argument. You shouldn't use it to signal something else. Create your own exception, and use chaining as explained in the above link.

Comment: If you just pass the message, yes, you lose information. The different types allow the caller to differentiate between situations. For example, if the problem was IOException, they may want to retry. You may decide to "swallow" some exceptions, though. For example, if you always use the same hard-coded algorithm and it's always available in any Android, you may "swallow" the `NoSuchArgumentException` because it will never actually happen.

Comment: No need to change anything.  Callers can simply write `catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e)`.  Or, you can declare your method with `throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this is a bit of style. Two choices make sense:

- you catch all these things and throw your own self-invented checked exception (wrapping around the original one)
- you do the same, and either use your own self-invented unchecked exception, or you simply wrap things into a new RuntimeException

Which way you choose is almost irrelevant (aka opinionated), the only really important thing is that your clearly document what exactly your API is doing, and when it will throw what.

Comment: In this case I was thinking of using the IllegalArgumentException because the exceptions are caused by the user passing in something to the method call that is not correct. If the truststore, keystore, keys, and certs are all correct, there will be no exception. But in general, I agree with your statement. I just want to avoid having the caller have to catch all those exceptions.